# OpenSSL - Building libssl and libcrypto

Tags: openssl

I have built OpenSSL long time with option `no-shared` (VS2017). For some reason now I need the DLLs too, so I removed `no-shared`. The project uses the new `libssl.lib` and `libcrypto.lib` and it works fine. Then I realized that this new libs contain DLL-stubs. I saw that there are also `libssl_static.lib` and `libcrypto_static.lib` in the buildfolder. When I open them with 7zip, they look like the old libs built with `no-share` (containing obj), but when I use them, the project throws:

```
LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__imp_strerror_s" ... (o_str.obj)
```

and a lot more of this messages. What is the difference between static built with `no-shared` and static built with "shared"?

I tried switching in project from `/MT` to `/MD` without success.

There is a secondary message `warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library`. Tried this but again no success.

Edit: I created the config once with shared and once with no-shared and diffed the makefiles. There is a comment concerning `libcrypto_static.lib` in the shared-makefile:

> The import library may look like a static library, but it is not. We MUST make the import library depend on the DLL, in case someone mistakenly removes the latter.

Am I right that I need the DLLs when I use the libs built with shared-option and it doesn't matter using `*.lib` or `*_static.lib`? But the file-sizes compared of the "real" static libs built with no-shared and the `*_static` files build with shared are nearly the same?

Answer (score 0):

You are conflating things a bit.

Okay, so you *also* need the OpenSSL DLLs, presumably for some other part of your software package, but you want to keep linking the static libs, right?

First things first

1. static libs: are `ar` archives with `.obj` files (with MSVC) and an index mapping object files to symbols
2. import libs: are `ar` archives with DLL import stubs, providing symbols (again with index) that are typically prefixed `__imp_`

   - These symbols (and the stubs underlying them) are created when you decorate a function `__declspec(dllexport)` or mention it in a [module definition file](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/build/reference/module-definition-dot-def-files) to create an import lib.
   - Conversely when *calling* DLL functions the use of `__declspec(dllimport)` on a function will cause the call to go to `__imp_functionname` instead of `functionname` (for brevity I am leaving out the topic of name mangling)
3. there are methods to create [hybrid libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75185166), too ... an oft overlooked fact! (not relevant to your question, however)

For brevity I will now proceed with `libcrypto.lib`/`libcrypto.dll` vs. `libcrypto_static.lib`, mostly ignoring possible other libraries you meant (including the default names for OpenSSL 3.x: `libcrypto-3.*` etc.).

By default **`libcrypto.lib` is an import library** (containing stubs to import from `libcrypto.dll` or whatever your DLL name) and `libcrypto.dll` contains the actual code used by your software when importing, whereas **`libcrypto_static.lib` is a static library** (containing the actual OpenSSL code).

### What is the difference between static built with no-shared and static built with "shared"?

`no-shared` will skip building the DLLs. The wording stems from the Unix side of things, where "shared libraries" are a similar concept used for dynamic linking. For all practical purposes you can assume that `no-shared` *means* `no-dlls`.

Conversely `shared` build the DLLs and corresponding import libraries.

### Am I right that I need the DLLs when I use the libs built with shared-option and it doesn't matter using `*.lib` or `*_static.lib`?

I *does* matter, but *functionally* they are equivalent, yes.

The difference is that when you link the **static library** all of the OpenSSL code will end up *in your binaries*. It also means that your binary needs a security update whenever OpenSSL receives a security update, which is why for this sort of library most people will recommend dynamic linking (DLL).

If on the other hand you link the **import library** the OpenSSL code will be external to your binaries. It lives in the DLL and you merely import the functionality by a mechanism that in this case is supplied by Windows (the loader).

### So what's the actual issue in your case?

Well, that's the thing. Your two raised questions have only little to do with the error you are getting:

```
LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__imp_strerror_s" ... (o_str.obj)
```

That error tells you that the object file `o_str.obj` -- and since you trimmed the error message it's not even evident whether this originates from the OpenSSL static library or your own code (I happen to know such a file exists in OpenSSL, though) -- that the linker was unable to find a symbol named `__imp_strerror_s` within all of the supplied *import libraries*.

Now the artificial distinction between import and static library is merely a convention (see "hybrid" topic linked above). I just know due to the prefix `__imp_` that the linker is looking for the import of a function named [`strerror_s`](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strerror-s-strerror-s-wcserror-s-wcserror-s). The linker -- technically -- does not care if you supply this symbol locally through an object file or a library, all it cares about is that none of the "entities" it is told to link together provides a symbol of the name `__imp_strerror_s`. By convention this prefix will only ever occur in import libraries.

As you can see from the linked documentation the function `strerror_s` is a C/C++ runtime -- or CRT -- function.

The setting `/NODEFAULTLIB:library` may play a role, but it's unclear here because you don't give enough detail.

`/MD` **should** have helped, unless `/NODEFAULTLIB` was used to expressly preclude `msvcrt.lib` from the list of default libraries to use. Of course if you built OpenSSL *static* libs with `/MD` that would be the very cause of your woes.

I dare say you probably built OpenSSL somehow wrongly. Why is that? Well, this function should not be referenced as `__imp_strerror_s` from `o_str.obj` but merely as `strerror_s`.

The reference comes from the `openssl_strerror_r` wrapper function. I built a fresh static library and and a dynamic library (see at the bottom) to test it and indeed in my case the call is not explicitly to the `__imp_`-prefixed name.

This suggests that your OpenSSL static lib was built with `/MD` and with preprocessor settings that cause the function `strerror_s` to be decorated with `__declspec(dllimport)` when seen by the compiler. Otherwise there is no explanation why the OpenSSL **static library** would insist to *import* this function instead of being agnostic about where the symbol comes from.

Because to the best of my knowledge for a call to `strerror_s` if not otherwise able to resolve the symbol, the linker would -- in a last ditch effort -- also try the `__imp_`-prefixed symbol. I think it tries variants anyway and name mangling plays into this and different rules apply depending on the target platform and architecture.

**NB:** For static building libs I would generally recommend using `/nodefaultlib` to remove *all* default library mentions from the static lib. Object files contained in the static lib have a `.drectve` section hardcoding *some* linker options *within* the library. This can be useful. For example OpenSSL usually will also require the import lib `ws2_32.lib` (Winsock2), so unless you give it explicitly you get a linker error in absence of that dependency being mentioned in `.drectve`. However, it is much more flexible **not** to overdo what goes into the `.drectve` and instead provide other mechanisms to supply the external dependencies (property sheets come to mind).

---

Btw, the arguably easiest way to build OpenSSL on Windows these days is to use [`vcpkg`](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg) with an NT script like this one from a Visual C++ Developer Prompt:

```
@echo off
set INSTALLDIR=%~dp0
vcpkg install openssl:x86-windows-static --x-install-root="%INSTALLDIR%openssl"
vcpkg install openssl:x64-windows-static --x-install-root="%INSTALLDIR%openssl"
```

That particular script corresponds to your original `no-shared` intent. If you want the DLLs you leave out the `-static`. Not sure if `vcpkg` provides a triplet that covers both at once, I built them separately.